# FsLexYacc. Lexing and Parsing with F#

Tags: parsing, f#, interpreter, lexer

I am trying to study the basics of the interpreters and compilers, using F# and FsLexYacc libraries, but I am having trouble of understanding the principles of writing the Lexer and Parser files... I was following [this example](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj0ruio9NnXAhWFKMAKHdoUC-gQFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikibooks.org%2Fwiki%2FF_Sharp_Programming%2FLexing_and_Parsing&usg=AOvVaw3tejbZ2oBBs_HhHwmUW10D), but it uses some simple SQL queries for the iterpreter.. What I am looking for, is how to convert [this grammar](http://www.cs.gettysburg.edu/~ilinkin/courses/Spring-2017/cs301/readings/pascal.pdf) into working Lexer and Parser using F#. 
I will include my AST, Lexer and Parser files if they will help.

This is AST

```
module Ast


type TypeIdentifier =
    |Boolean of bool
    |Integer of int
    |Float of float
    |String of string

and BinaryOperators = 
    |Add
    |Subtract
    |Multiply
    |Equal
    |NotEqual
    |Less
    |Greater
    |LessEqual
    |GreaterEqual
    |Semicolon
    |Colon
    |Range
    |Assign
```

This is Lexer

```
{
module SqlLexer
open System
open SqlParser
open Microsoft.FSharp.Text.Lexing

let keywords = [

    "div", DIV;
    "or", OR;
    "and", AND;
    "not", NOT;
    "if", IF;
    "then", THEN;
    "else", ELSE;
    "of", OF;
    "while", WHILE;
    "do", DO;
    "array", ARRAY;
    "procedure", PROCEDURE;
    "program", PROGRAM;
    "begin", BEGIN;
    "end", END;
    "var", VAR

] |> Map.ofList

let ops = [

    "+", ADD;
    "-", SUBTRACT;
    "*", MULTIPLY;
    "=", EQUAL;
    "<>", NOTEQUAL;
    "<", LESS;
    "<=", LESSEQUAL;
    ">", GREATER;
    ">=", GREATEREQUAL;
    ":=", ASSIGN;
    ".", POINT;
    ",", COMMA;
    ";", SEMICOLON;
    ":", COLON;
    "..", RANGE;

] |> Map.ofList 
}

let char                = ['a'-'z' 'A'-'Z']
let digit               = ['0'-'9']
let int                 = '-'?digit+
let float               = '-'?digit+ '.' digit+
let identifier          = char(char|digit)*
let whitespece          = [' ' '\t']
let newline             = "\n\r" | '\n' | '\r'
let operator            = "+" | "-" | "*" | "=" | "<>" | "<" | "<=" | ">" | ">=" | ":=" | "." | "," | ";" | ":" | ".."

rule tokenize = parse
| whitespace        { tokenize lexbuf }
| newline           { lexbuf.EndPos <- lexbuf.EndPos.NextLine; tokenise lexbuf; }
| int               { INT(Int32.Parse(LexBuffer<_>.LexemeString lexbuf)) }
| float             { FLOAT(Double.Parse(LexBuffer<_>.LexemeString lexbuf) }
| operator          { ops.[LexBuffer<_>.LexemeString lexbuf] }
| identifier        { match keywords.TryFind(LexBuffer<_>.LexemeString lexbuf) with
                        | Some(token) -> token
                        | None -> ID(LexBuffer<_>.LexemeString lexbuf)}
| eof               { EOF }
```

And this is my Parser:

```
%{
open Sql
%}

%token <string> ID
%token <int> INT
%token <float> FLOAT
%token <bool> BOOL

%token DIV
%token AND OR NOT
%token IF THEN ELSE
%token WHILE DO
%token ARRAY OF
%token PROGRAM 
%token PRODEDURE
%token BEGIN END
%token VAR

%token ADD SUBTRACT MULTIPLY
%token EQUAL NOTEQUAL
%token LESS LESSEQUAL
%token GREATER GREATEREQUAL
%token ASSIGN
%token POINT COMMA RANGE
%token SEMICOLON COLON

%start start 

start: 
    PROGRAM ID ;
    block .
    EOF {
        identifier = {$2}
        block = {$4}
    }

block:
    |variableDeclarationPart procedureDeclaretionPart statementPart {$1, $2, $3}

variableDeclarationPart:
    |   {}
    |VAR variableDeclaration ; {variableDeclaration;} {}
```

I am not looking for an answer with written code, I would like explanation with some similar example or a tutorial that uses FsLexYacc libraries to interpret programming languages like Pascal

Answer (score 1):

I've been struggling with this quite some time ago. What I end up doing was that since the FsLexYacc library is based on lex and yacc I've got through quick tutorial on bare lex and yacc (or flex & bison) except instead of using C syntax I was converting it to the F# and using it in my test project.
After getting through the concepts I've gone through
https://github.com/fsprojects/FsLexYacc/blob/master/docs/content/jsonParserExample.md as well as made my own implementation of some esoteric language.

Hope this would help.

PS: F# compiler is open source and it is using FsLexYacc so you can try to read that stuff as well.